# Como faço para exibir o conteúdo das minhas paginas de wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Minha pagina está com header e footer e gostaria de colocar o conteúdo entre elas, sei que deve ser uma coisa simples.

```
          <?php
                if ( have_posts() ): 
                while ( have_posts() ): 
                    the_post();
                endwhile; 
                else:
                    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'devhub' 
                );
                endif;
          ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar as [**Template Tags**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/), que buscam as informações específicas que você quer, por exemplo, `the_content` ou `the_title` pra trazer o texto e o título.

Aqui um exemplo do tema [TwentyFifteen](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/content.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php
        // Post thumbnail.
        twentyfifteen_post_thumbnail();
    ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
            if ( is_single() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
            endif;
        ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
            the_content( sprintf(
                __( 'Continue reading %s', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
            ) );

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
                'pagelink'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>%',
                'separator'   => '<span class="screen-reader-text">, </span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <?php
        // Author bio.
        if ( is_single() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ) :
            get_template_part( 'author-bio' );
        endif;
    ?>

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php twentyfifteen_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfifteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Ricardo ainda não consegui, consigo colocar o "the_title();" mas o "the_content()" não aparece nada, nem mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1):

É só colocar "the_content();" depois do while ( have_posts() ): the_post();, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
      <?php
            if ( have_posts() ): 
            while ( have_posts() ): the_post();

            the_content();

            endwhile; 
            else:
                _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'devhub' 
            );
            endif;
      ?>
```